# CodeIgniter - upload multiple text entries and files from single form

Tags: codeigniter

I have a single form on a page. It has 5 text fields and 3 upload file fields. I need to write  the text and file paths to a database. I have seen many examples online but most are to upload a single file or to upload multiple files from the same upload field.

I am new to CodeIgniter so code snippets would be very helpful.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another suggestion would be:

```
function upload()
{
    $config['upload_path'] = $path; //$path=any path you want to save the file to...
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg'; //this is the file types allowed
    $config['max_size'] = '1024'; //max file size

    $config['max_width']  = '1024';//if file type is image
    $config['max_height']  = '768';//if file type is image

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    foreach($_FILES as $Key => $File)
    {
        if($File['size'] > 0)
        {
            if($this->upload->do_upload($Key))
            {
                $data = $this->upload->data();
                echo $data['file_name'];
            }
            else
            {
                // throw error
                echo $this->upload->display_errors();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This will automatically work for ALL file inputs you post and it doesn't care about the name or quantity :)

Comment: I ran into another problem. When I go to write the form entries to the data base, I can do the text just fine, but how would I write the filenames to their corresponding fields in the database? Since we are looping through..

Comment: `$data` contains the information returned from `$this->upload->data()` - see the user guide at http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html

Comment: @Gavin Hi sir, What if user mix it up some nonimage files with images and upload that data??  I tried this case and get that some images are getting uploaded and then the error came up. Any solution for this?

Comment: @ankitsuthar Hey - If I recall correctly, the error is likely down to the `allowed_types` configuration. If you updated the `allowed_types` to include other types you want to accept and uploaded a mixture of images and say, word documents, only those identifiable as an image (i.e. image/gif, image/png) will be validated against the `max_width` and `max_height` restrictions. Hope that helps?

Comment: @Gavin Here is my question, sir. Hope You can help me on this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41630185/multiple-image-uploading-error-in-codeigniter

Answer (score 1):

HOpe this helps

```
$config['upload_path'] = $path; //$path=any path you want to save the file to...
$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg'; //this is the file types allowed
$config['max_size'] = '1024'; //max file size

$config['max_width']  = '1024';//if file type is image
$config['max_height']  = '768';//if file type is image
//etc config for file properties, you can check all of them out on website
```

now suppose you have 3 files, which you want to save as **1.jpg, 2.jpg,3.gif**, which are uploaded through 3 input fields, **pic1, pic2, pic3** here is what you do

```
for($ite=1;$ite<=3;$ite++){
    if(!empty($_FILES["pic".$ite]["name"])){ //if file is present
        $ext = pathinfo($_FILES['pic'.$ite]['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION); //get extension of file
        $config["file_name"]="$ite.$ext"; //rename file to 1.jpg,2.jpg or 3.jpg, depending on file number and its extension

        $this->upload->initialize($config); //upload library of codeigniter initialize function with config properties set earlier
        if(!$this->upload->do_upload("pic".$ite)){
            //error code

        }

        }
    }
```